# KeyError: 'target_text' while training a t5 model using simple transformers

Tags: python

I am training a T5 model using Simple transformers and that is giving keyError:'target_text'
what could be The probable cause of it and how can I solve this?
here is my code

```
    !pip install SimpleTransformers

  

import logging
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('/content/Vastu - Sheet1 (4).csv',sep=',')
df

df["prefix"]="ask_question"

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_df, eval_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.05)
train_df.keys()

from simpletransformers.t5 import T5Model ,T5Args

model_args=T5Args()
model_args.num_train_epochs = 3


model = T5Model(
    model_type='t5',
    model_name="t5-base",
    args=model_args,
    use_cuda=False,
    
    
)

model.train_model(train_df)
```

Comment: There' no trace of `target_text` on your code, were do you use the variable?

Comment: Thank you, I got to know there was a mistake in the index name...it has space before target_text